# Power BI mobile - how to notify end user that data has changed?

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerapps, power-automate

I'm quite newbie to Power BI.

I have a published report, and want to know how the end user of PBI mobile version is informed (pushed notification) that data like date has changed?
I know that the end user can turn some sort of notifications/alerts, but I doubt that my CEO's will know how to mend it( training them how to do it is not an option :(

Can I as the owner of the report set some sort of notification as a general ? For example when the date is changed, all end users will get the notification on their smartphones ?

I'm thinking about Power Automate, but I'm not sure/don't know how to set this up.

Any help/tip will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerBI you can [create a data alert to send you a notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-set-data-alerts). By default, the data alert is an in-app alert but there is in an option to have it also send you an email.

Unfortunately, there is no capability in PowerBI to set an alert for another user.

You can use a Power Automate Flow to meet your requirement:

*Before starting, be sure you've configured your Data Alert, the Flow will connect to PowerBI to find your data alerts*

1. Go to http://make.powerapps.com
2. Select **Flows** -> **New flow** -> **Automated cloud flow**

[image]

3. Search on Power to find and select the **When a data driven alert is triggered** trigger. Give your Flow a name (optional.)
   [image]
4. Power Automate will connect to your PowerBI instance and find the available data alerts. You will select the appropriate data alert from the drop-down.

[image]

5. You can now build out the rest of your flow based on how you want the user notified. If your organization makes use of Teams you send a notification in Teams, using the Teams Connector. Email will be all around most universal easiest and not require a premium connector license. You could also deploy a PowerApp to your users and send a push notification to the PowerApp (but that will take more work and some experience/familiarity with Power Apps Canvas.)

[image]

Comment: thanks, 
I was trying to use those "Notifications" but the don't effect the power BI mobile app. Is there a way to force push notifications on end user mobile app ?